# ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 1: Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE (SALARY*MONTHS)=MAX(SALARY*MONTHS)
```

I am trying to get the number of employees that have the highest (salary*months). Why am I getting this error even without a group by? Is it that I am supposed to have that?

Comment: You cannot use aggregation functions outside of the SELECT and HAVING clauses. Any aggregate function use implies a GROUP BY, omitting one is essentially grouping into one result row.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting this error because `MAX()` is an aggregation function, so generally MySQL is expecting a `GROUP BY`.

For this logic, you can use a *subquery*:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM EMPLOYEE e
WHERE (e2.SALARY * e2.MONTHS) = (SELECT MAX(e2.SALARY* e2.MONTHS) FROM EMPLOYEE e2);
```